# How many passwords per second can a typical computer check?

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking

I wanna know how many passwords per second my computer can check this is for brute force attacks. I looked everywhere and on this [website](http://www.lockdown.co.uk/?pg=combi&s=articles#Classes) and the computer listed on here are nothing similar to the one I have. I have a i7 6500u @2.50GHz processor 16GB ram and a AMD radeon graphics card 2GB.

Comment: Your computer can crack millions of passwords per second... I might be right, I might be wrong. It can depend on many things such as the complexity of the passwords , the hashing algorithm used and how efficient your brute force application is, to name a few. Your question needs to be a bit more specific

Comment: millions with good CPUs, billions with good GPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) on your computer. This is a password recovery tool, and it has a [benchmark option](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#how_can_i_perform_a_benchmark) that you can run like so:

```
$ ./hashcat64.bin -b
```

Comment: i did download it but it says i need OpenCL or a Nvidia gpu